# manage image with Pop up

Tags: c#

I had image for Products and i want user when click on image appear image as popup  with big size and save it

as
http://www.istockphoto.com/file_browse.php?exu=1&action=abstracttype&value=15&page=4

Comment: Can you provide more information.  Windows, Web etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you need? (very hard to guess from your question)

[ASP.NET JavaScript Image Popup Done Right](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/ASP.NET-Code/JavaScript-Image-Popups-Done-Right/)

Comment: thank you i did it with this java script code
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

var newwindow = ''
function popitup(url) {
if (newwindow.location && !newwindow.closed) {
    newwindow.location.href = url;
    newwindow.focus(); }
else {
    newwindow=window.open(url,'htmlname','width=404,height=316,resizable=1');}
}

function tidy() {
if (newwindow.location && !newwindow.closed) {
   newwindow.close(); }
}
</script>

Comment: but there is a problem in browser please check it in fire fox and safari it worked well in internet explorer 
http://beta.elarabygroup.com/Model.aspx?Product_Id=80